# How to send data from Embedded lightning component back to Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I am having trouble finding this information.

I am finding lots of stuff on communicating between a lightning component and Visualforce page when the Visualforce page is embedded inside the lightning component as an iframe, which involves doing postMessages and what not.

However, my situation is that I have a Visualforce page that I put a lightning component on.

I want the user to fill out the form in the lightning component, then click 'OK', and be able to get that info back on the Visualforce page. However, I am unsure how you perform this kind of communication. The Lightning component is not in an iframe when you embed it in a Visualforce page, so doing some complicated postMessage should not be necessary.

Comment: You should be able to pass in a callback as an attribute when you instantiate the lightning component. I've done it before, but am not sure if Salesforce blocks this now... give me a few mins and I may get time to provide an example.

Comment: Sure, I'd like to see an example of this. Do I just set it up like: `$Lightning.createComponent('c:myComponent',{'callback': someFunctionOnVFPage}, function(cmp){});` ? Hmm... I am unsure how you then trigger that from the Lightning component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To communicate from the component to the VisualForce page, use a callback function. For example:

```
 <script>
 var someFunctionOnVFPage = function(param){
   alert(param);
 }

 $Lightning.createComponent('c:myComponent',
 {'callback':   someFunctionOnVFPage}, 
 function(cmp){});
```

In the component:

```
component.get('v.callback')('hey vf page!!');
```

Comment: Very nice, what do you put the callback to as far as attribute type goes?

Comment: Just make it an object... due to Javascript's type system, it can be anything, really.